# React is stating "'dataTable' is defined but never used no-unused-vars" but I am using the variable

Tags: reactjs, es6-modules

I am trying to render my dataTable component onto my App.js file in React. I made sure to import it using ES6 Syntax but for some reason it's not recognising the import variable. I tried reloading VScode but it's still not rendering.

Here's my dataTable index file:

```
import './dataTable.css'

const dataTable = () => {
  return (
    <div className='data_container'>dataTable</div>
  )
}

export default dataTable
```

And here's my App.js file:

```
import dataTable from "./components/dataTable";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <dataTable />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I also took some screenshots:[image: I did save the files and it's still saying it's undefined]

Answer (score 2):

All React component names must start with a capital letter. If you start a component name with a lowercase letter, it will be treated like a built-in element like a `<div>` or a `<span>`.

Comment: I forgot . It's been a minute since I code with React and I forgot that basic concept. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using renaming the component to `DataTable`